# remove Label layout from Bokeh fig after updating curdoc()

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a multi-panel Bokeh plot, rendered with the Bokeh server (Bokeh 0.12.14). I am running a function with a button widget (`on_click()`) that modifies my `gridplot` layout, adds some labels, and exports a customized .png image. In the function, I use `curdoc().hold()` followed by `curdoc().clear`, make my modifications to the figures and built a new `gridplot`. I then use `curdoc().add_root(gridplot)` with the modified gridplot layout and run `export_png(curdoc())`.

After the export, I run `curdoc().clear()` again, rebuild my original `gridplot` layout, and restore the original document with `curdoc().add_root(gridplot)`. Finally ending with `curdoc().unhold()`.

Everything works fine, except I cannot figure out how to remove the custom labels created for the .png export. I am adding several labels such as:

```
  season_label = Label(x=start_display, y=35, x_units='data', y_units='data',
             text= '%s - %s' % (starting_year, starting_year+1),
             render_mode='css', text_font_style='bold',
             text_font_size='14px', text_baseline='middle', text_align='left')

  newsnow_extra_fig.add_layout(season_label)
```

Is there a way to remove a layout from a figure?

Answer (score 1):

As a work-around, I discovered that I can add text annotations as [Div widgets](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html#div), instead of as [Labels](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#labels). I then add the widget either above or below the intended figure with `gridplot()`. For example:

```
div_1 = bkm.widgets.Div(text="""My text annotation {} - {}""".format(starting_year, starting_year+1),
    width=1400, height=27, style={'background-color':'white'})

div_wb_1 = widgetbox(div_1)

grid = gridplot(div_wb_1,
                fig_1,
                fig_2,
                div_wb_2,
                ncols=1)
```

After the .png export, I am then able to rebuild my original document by redefining `grid` without the div widget boxes:

```
grid = gridplot(fig_1,
                fig_2,
                ncols=1)
```

However, when I add `gridplot()` (including the divs) to the `curdoc()` and then `export_png(curdoc())`, the background is transparent between the div widgets and the figures (even with defining `'background-color':'white'` in the html) -- I need a white background across the entire .png. To fix this, I open the image, edit the background to be white using PIL (Python Imaging Library), and then re-save the image. This makes the entire server-side process much slower than I would like for the client who is hitting an "Export Image" widget button.

I'm posting this as an answer to my own question as it solves the problem, but **it would be great to simply remove a Label layout from the figure, if possible!**

For reference, [here](https://btac-web-plots.herokuapp.com/avyview?style=snowpacktracker) is my web application, using this answer for the function of the 'EXPORT IMAGE' button.